# State appears as empty object in redux dev tools

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm somewhat hesitant to ask the questions as I don't know what detail to share to help get an answer. Here is the issue:

App is working fine. All data is in state as I can print it out in the console and consume it in the React app. However, as show in the picture below state as show in react dev tools is 'Empty object'. This is the same for the Chrome & Firefox extensions as well as the stand-alone version of react dev tools. It is true for every level of the component tree.

[image: State is 'empty object']

The app is React using create-react-app with a custom express server proxied through the client. Running in dev. Data is coming from MongoDB.

Thoughts I had for debugging
1) try different versions of related npm packages
2) create a stripped down / simplified version of the app to see if the problem is there and if not, build back up to see where it gets introduced.

I obviously don't want to do #2 so was hoping someone could suggest what the problem might be.

Comment: `state` in dev tool is internal state of the selected component, not the redux state. Try component which has internal state.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara, thanks for your comment. By 'internal state' do you mean having this.state = {...} in the component's constructor? If so, I'm looking at a sample app from the book 'Developing a Redux Edge. It does not use this.state = {...} at all but still you can see state in dev tools.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure why. But I checked one of my react/redux app and it has the same behavior. Btw I'm using react-devtools and not sure you are referring the same thing as redux dev tool.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara, I'm speaking of the 'React Devtools' browser extension as well as the stand-alone react-devtools app. Behavior is the same in both.

Answer (score 1):

Each React component have its own internal state, which you can access via `this.state.yourPropertyName` and set via `this.setState({yourPropertyName: 'someValue'})`. This state is part of React. If you want to pass the data in your React component's state, you'll have to pass it as `props` to its child component.

Redux is a separate library independent of React. Redux helps you manage your app's state by using a global state that can be accessed by any of your react component using the `connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)`. When you `connect()` a component, it creates a wrapper React component (like the one you have selected `<Connect(Page)>` component which takes care of connecting to the Redux store and passing to your `<Page>` component as props. That's the reason you access the Redux state from your component as `this.props.myProperty`.

The Chrome extension you are looking at is the React-devtools. The `state` section there refers to the React's internal state. If you select the `<Page>` component, you'll probably see the data from the Redux store under the `props` section.

If you want to view your Redux state, you can use https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension or from the React-devtools, select the `<Provider>` component and type `$r.store.getState()` in the console.